# What are the three or four holes on the back of a 3.5inch floppy disk indicating and used for?

Tags: floppy-disk

Why do 3.5 inch floppy disks have sometimes three and others four holes on the backside? What's the difference, what do this holes indicate and what are these used for?

[image: 3.5inch floppy disk back with 4 holes]
[image: 3.5inch floppy disk back with 3 holes]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**The upper two** (or one) notches at the sides, are to grab and clamp the disk against ejection - an addition Sony made to the 3.5 design on request by Apple, which had that already [patented](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4466033) for the twiggy drive.

**The lower two** round holes are for precision alignment used during production to hold it exact in place. They may as well be used by some of the higher capacity drives, like [LS-120/Superdisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperDisk).

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. It seems you're the master of floppies, considering my other questions you've answered. As I couldn't find it, do you know of any visual representation of the ejection mechanism that demonstrates this? A video? Some photos? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any references?

Comment: The holes 'used for alignment' engage a feature in floppy drives that will not allow the disk to seat correctly if they are absent or misplaced.

Comment: I found a video related to that ejection mechanism here: https://youtu.be/69WWqwEeslY?t=80

Answer (score 1):

The diskette housing is pressed down onto alignment pins that engage
two of those holes, which keeps the motor axis at the
right position that the diskette is free to rotate in its
housing (doesn't rub the sides) and the sliding door on
the diskette engages the retraction finger.

A third hole is for the write-protect tab, while
a fourth is indicative of high data density (a superfloppy holds 1.4 Mbytes, while 'standard' doublesided hold 720k
to 800k bytes).

Comment: You are looking at the wrong holes. None of the encircled holes have to do with write protect tab or signaling high density. The write protect tab is the slide mechanism at the bottom of the image.

Comment: The notches don't engage anything; the 'four holes' reference opens the question to the other features.

Comment: @Whit3rd that's not how [frame challenges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263661/does-stack-exchange-allow-for-answers-which-question-the-validity-or-stance-of-t) work. You're supposed to solve the real problem. Not insist that this is literally what you asked.

Comment: It's so weird to be old enough to having been using floppies regularly at one time, yet young enough so that a floppy is "obviously" 1.44 MB as "standard".